# Lining tables with wrapping in html emails

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have 3 images with captions that are placed in 3 separate tables (for formatting). I need them to line up i a row but when some width is exceeded, I need them to stack in 1 column.

Is this possible, bearing in mind limitations of email clients (e.g. can't use `display:inline-block` as it's not covered by all browsers), to achieve this result?

```html
<table style="width:100%; max-width:300px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <!-- Image GROUP -->

        <!-- Image 1 -->
        <table style="width:100%; max-width:100px">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=%20" style="width:100%; max-width:100px" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <p>Image title</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- Image 2 -->
        <table style="width:100%; max-width:100px">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=%20" style="width:100%; max-width:100px" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <p>Image title</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- Image 3 -->
        <table style="width:100%; max-width:100px">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=%20" style="width:100%; max-width:100px" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <p>Image title</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>


      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k4dxbo22/

Comment: So no `display: table` either?

Answer (score 0):

It's normally best to practice to style outside the html file. Reason being is that when the code starts getting larger you don't want to modify one item at a time.
In this case one of many options is to wrap each table with `<div></div>` and add classes to them. 
Once you assign a class or you can do this in your html file, whichever you prefer, you can use the `float` property to achieve what you want. 
In this case `float:left;`. If you do not apply any `float` property the html doc will stack vertically by default.
Also, note that when setting width's it might overflow to the next row. See example

```css
.table1{
  float:left;
}

.table2{
  float:left;
}

.table3{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
        <!-- Image 1 -->

<div class="table1">

        <table style="width:100%; max-width:100px">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=%20" style="width:100%; max-width:100px"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <p>Image title</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

  
</div>

<div class="table2">

        <table style="width:100%; max-width:100px">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=%20" style="width:100%; max-width:100px"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <p>Image title</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

  
</div>


<div class="table3">

        <table style="width:100%; max-width:100px">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=%20" style="width:100%; max-width:100px"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <p>Image title</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a JS solution, as having `float: left;` on the elements will just have them lining one beside the other.

So, check these JSFiddles:

1. If you have big items, or they are not able to get lined up because of the accumulated width, then my code will remove the class *floated* (if it has it), which in turn will stack the images one on top of the other. [Here] is this fiddle[1](https://jsfiddle.net/Ahm7777/k4dxbo22/10/).
2. On the other hand, if the items have enough room to get one beside the other, then my code will make sure to add the *floated* class to each of them. This code is sequential, so if ay of the images is big enough to push the others, then the classes will be removed and the iteration will stop. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ahm7777/k4dxbo22/12/) is the fiddle of this one.

This is the best solution I could think off to make sure the items can be stacked and lined up correctly when the need arise.

Play around with the code to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but email clients doesn't do JS and probably float:left;. :(